# Ordenar uma lista encadeada com algoritmo Selection em Java

Tags: java, algoritmo, estrutura-de-dados, classificação, order

Estou trabalhando com algoritmos de ordenação. Implementei ordenando com 
Bubble sort, entretanto é preciso implementar com um exemplo em que o algoritmo não seja estável( Selection ,Quicksort, Heapsort ou Introsort).
A ideia é ordenar uma lista de inteiros

---

***Implementação com Bubble sort***

---

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class Ordenação {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
          List<Integer> lista = new LinkedList<Integer>();

            lista.add(5);
            lista.add(3);
            lista.add(1);
            lista.add(2);
            lista.add(4);
            ordenacaoBubleSort(lista);     
    }


 public static  void ordenacaoBubleSort(List<Integer> lista) {

     for(int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
         for(int j = 0; j < (lista.size() - 1 - i); j++) {
             if(lista.get(j) > lista.get(j + 1)) {
                 Integer aux = lista.get(j);
                 lista.set(j, lista.get(j + 1));
                 lista.set(j + 1, aux);
             }
             System.out.println(lista);

         }
     }

     System.out.println(lista);
 }

//public static void ordenacaoSelecao(List<Integer>lista) {

//}



}
```

***Como poderia adaptar este algoritmo Selection utilizando uma lista ?***

```
    public void selectionSort(int vetor[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < vetor.length; i++) {
        int posicaoMenor = i;
        for (int j = (i + 1); j < vetor.length; j++) {
            if (vetor[j] < vetor[posicaoMenor]) {
                posicaoMenor = j;
            }
        }
        if (vetor[i] != vetor[posicaoMenor]) {
            int temp = vetor[i];
            vetor[i] = vetor[posicaoMenor];
            vetor[posicaoMenor] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: E sua dúvida seria qual?

Comment: Editei o código, minha dúvida seria como poderia adptar o Código selection de um integer para uma lista<integer>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu método adaptado para uma lista fica assim. Dê uma olhada nos comentários do código para entender as mudanças necessárias:

```
private static void selectionSort(List<Integer> vetor) {
        // o método size() retorna o tamanho de uma lista
        // (é o equivale ao length do array)
        for (int i = 0; i < vetor.size(); i++) {
            int posicaoMenor = i;
            for (int j = (i + 1); j < vetor.size(); j++) {
                //o método get() acessa o valor em uma determinada posição da lista
                //é o equivalente ao vetor[j] do array
                if (vetor.get(j) < vetor.get(posicaoMenor)) {
                    posicaoMenor = j;
                }
            }
            if (vetor.get(i) != vetor.get(posicaoMenor)) {
                int temp = vetor.get(i);
                //o método set() substitui um valor por outro em
                //uma determinada posição da lista
                //o primeiro parâmetro é onde eu quero mudar,
                //o segundo é o que eu quero colocar no lugar
                vetor.set(i, vetor.get(posicaoMenor));
                vetor.set(posicaoMenor, temp);
            }
        }
    }
```

E um método de teste:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   List<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<>();
   Collections.addAll(lista, 5, 1, 8, 2, 9);
   selectionSort(lista);
   System.out.println(lista); //imprime [1, 2, 5, 8, 9]
}
```

Se ficou alguma dúvida, só perguntar. Senão, só marque como resolvida. ;)